# Вычисление индексов цифры числа пи на отрезке

Tags: числа, численные-методы

Существует ли способ найти индексы(номер цифры после запятой) какой-либо конкретной цифры (0-9) числа пи на ограниченном отрезке индексов? Причём необходимо сделать это как минимум за O(n), хотя чем быстрее тем лучше!
К примеру, на отрезке от 1 до 4 индексы для цифры 1 будут 1 и 3, ведь пи равен

3,14159...

0 12345... - индексы.

Смотрел формулу Бэйли — Боруэйна — Плаффа, не придумал как адекватно выразить оттуда то что нужно. И не очень-то понял как она работает.

Также будет неплохо, если есть такой способ для числа е или другого, в котором последовательность чисел после запятой совершенно случайна.

Comment: Вас точно интересуют десятичные цифры? Был какой-то метод получить любую n-ю цифру числа Пи, не просчитывая для этого все предыдущие.

Comment: Вот этот метод: Бэйли — Боруэйна — Плаффа
Пожалуй не принципиально, можно и в 16ричном. Но у меня задача другая - надо на отрезке найти, тогда уж, все индексы конкретной 16ричной цифры

Comment: Так за чем дело стало? Перебор всех индексов отрезка; вычисление n-й цифры по [формуле](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bailey%E2%80%93Borwein%E2%80%93Plouffe_formula) ( см. секцию "BBP digit-extraction algorithm for π"); "она - не она?".

Comment: Забыл указать, что необходима сложность меньше чем О(n). Т.е. тупой перебор всех чисел отрезка не подходит(

  Я пытался выразить тот самый n из формулы, чтобы получать индексы числа за log(n), но не получилось. 

  Пока что, если пробегать полностью по всем индексам сложность O(n)*log(n).

Сейчас я понял, что не обязательно этот алгоритм нужен для числа пи, для е тоже подойдёт.